# magento 2 block duplication

Tags: magento2, full-page-cache

i am facing a problem in my custom module. my configuration cache is getting invalidate and when i click on pager or Pagination link, the phtml renders in URL Bar.

**URL Bar:**
[image]

[image]

and the block is being duplicate after the page loads.
[image]